# Error "Compass can't find any Sass files to compile." on compass create

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ubuntu, rubygems, sass, compass

I am getting the following error when running `compass create my-theme -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap`:

```
$ compass create my-theme -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
directory my-theme/ 
   create my-theme/config.rb 
Compass can't find any Sass files to compile.
Is your compass configuration correct?.
If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help.
```

I get this error in any directory where I run the command above.

### How can I solve this problem?

Relevant output:

```
$ compass --version
Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)
Copyright (c) 2008-2014 Chris Eppstein
Released under the MIT License.
Compass is charityware.
Please make a tax deductable donation for a worthy cause: http://umdf.org/compass
$ sass --version
Sass 3.4.5 (Selective Steve)
$ gem --version
2.2.2
```

Comment: I'm seriously re-evaluating if SASS is really worth it, since it is 'yet another layer to debug and maintain'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a wrong configuration somewhere. By reinstalling `ruby`, `gem`, `sass` and `compass` this should be fixed.

#### Install `aptitude`

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

### Cleaning

#### Uninstall `ruby`

```
sudo aptitude purge ruby
```

Be sure you don't have any other ruby packages (e.g. `ruby2.1`)

```
sudo aptitude purge ruby2.1
```

#### Remove executables that were not removed via `aptitude`

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/sass
sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/compass
```

### Fresh install

#### `ruby`

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full rubygems-integration
```

#### `sass`

```
sudo gem install sass
```

#### `compass`

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Now we have a fresh install of `ruby`, `gem`, `sass` and `compass`.

---

Let's check if everything is working nice now:

```
$ compass create my-theme -r bootstrap-sass --using bootstrap
directory my-theme/ 
directory my-theme/fonts/bootstrap/ 
directory my-theme/javascripts/ 
directory my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/ 
directory my-theme/sass/ 
directory my-theme/stylesheets/ 
   create my-theme/config.rb 
   create my-theme/sass/styles.scss 
   create my-theme/sass/_bootstrap-variables.scss 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap.js 
   create my-theme/javascripts/bootstrap-sprockets.js 
   create my-theme/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
   create my-theme/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot 
   create my-theme/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg 
   create my-theme/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf 
    write my-theme/stylesheets/styles.css

*********************************************************************
Congratulations! Your compass project has been created.

You may now add and edit sass stylesheets in the sass subdirectory of your project.

Sass files beginning with an underscore are called partials and won't be
compiled to CSS, but they can be imported into other sass stylesheets.

You can configure your project by editing the config.rb configuration file.

You must compile your sass stylesheets into CSS when they change.
This can be done in one of the following ways:
  1. To compile on demand:
     compass compile [path/to/project]
  2. To monitor your project for changes and automatically recompile:
     compass watch [path/to/project]

More Resources:
  * Website: http://compass-style.org/
  * Sass: http://sass-lang.com
  * Community: http://groups.google.com/group/compass-users/


To import your new stylesheets add the following lines of HTML (or equivalent) to your webpage:
<head>
  <link href="/stylesheets/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Comment: I found I had to also manually install ruby-json in order to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable, compass chokes on directories with spaces (I think, and at least on a Windows machine).

I have resolved it by creating a junction from the repository into a folder without spaces - see this awesome utility: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html

And food for thought: consider if SASS is needed, do you want to debug your SASS or CSS?

[image: sass-can-not-find-any-files-fix]